# Creating many instances of a chart via a loop based on an names array

Tags: c#, arrays, charts

So basically I want to have a bunch of charts (there will be quite a lot of them) with the same structure created via a loop. Is there a way to generate all of them (also Chart Areas and Series names) based on an array of their names (A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3...), also changing the location of the each new one?

I'm really new to C# and would greatly appreciate any help. Hope there is a solution. Thank you!

The code of a single chart looks like this (there are some more lines but I'll just show the structure):

```
public Main()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea A1_area =
    new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();

    this.A1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();

    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = 
    new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series2 = 
    new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();

    A1_area.Position.Auto = false;
    this.A1.ChartAreas.Add(A1_area);
    this.A1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(216, 43);

    series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
    series1.Name = "Series1";
    series2.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
    series2.Name = "Series2";

    this.A1.Series.Add(series1);
    this.A1.Series.Add(series2);

    this.A1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 34);
    this.A1.TabStop = false;
    this.A1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.A1_Click);
}

private void A1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart A1;
```

Comment: Have you considered to use array/list of charts?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried to use list but I couldn't get it to work. I googled for any similar examples, but didn't find any. Maybe you can give me a hint or any link on smth similar?

Comment: `I googled for any similar examples, but didn't find any` Be the first one to create such an incredible code....

Comment: Well, I'm just learning. Enjoying the experience so far but I don't think I'm capable of creating something that complicated myself yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should put this line with the other include statements to allow for easier syntax:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

I'm also not exactly sure what you actually want to accomplish, but this is what I think you asked for (untested):

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string[] chartNames = { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3" };
        List<Chart> charts = new List<Chart>;
        int i = 0;
        foreach(string cname in chartNames)
        {
            i++;
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
            Chart thisChart = new Chart();
            Series series1 = new Series();
            Series series2 = new Series();
            chartArea.Position.Auto = false;
            thisChart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
            //each chart will be 43 units higher than the last
            thisChart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(216, (43*i));
            series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100; 
            series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
            series1.Name = "Series1";
            series2.Name = "Series2";
            thisChart.Series.Add(series1);
            thisChart.Series.Add(series2);
            thisChart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 34);
            thisChart.TabStop = false;
            //sets the name of this chart to the corresponding string from the array of names
            thisChart.Name = cname;          
            thisChart.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.chartClick);
            //add this chart to the list of charts
            charts.Add(thisChart);
        }     
    }

    private void chartClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //you can differentiate between charts using the sender.name property
        Chart senderChart = (Chart)sender;
        if(senderChart.Name == "A1")
        {
            //if the chart with name A1 is clicked...
        }
    }
```

Also, you could use code like the following within the foreach loop, to set the area for a specific chart name:

```
            if(cname == "A1")
            {
                //set properties for chart with name A1
                series1.Name = "A1 series 1";
                series2.Name = "A2 series 2";
                thisChart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);
            }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your time! This solution definitely works exactly how I wanted to. Also setting names with a foreach loop should come in handy.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet but can let you know where to start.  I have not used the chart class but classes are classes.  Not know specifics I am taking a stab at the dark.  You want a list of names in an array to create a list of charts with 1 chartarea, 2 series with set values.  names of charts and chart areas named after names in array.  Here we go.  You will need a method.  The method will return a list of the object Chart object.  The Name property in both the Chart and the ChartArea inside the Chart property will be used to reference specific charts by name but the entire list will be whatever you put it in.  Here we go.  First, I don't like long name spaces so i would add the below line to make typing shorter.

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

private List<Chart> MakeCharts(string[] YourArray)
{
    var myChart = new List<Chart>();
    Foreach(string chName in YourArray)
    {
        ChartArea area = new ChartArea();
        area.Name = chName;
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.Name = chName;
        Series series1 = new Series();
        Series series2 = new Series();

        area.Position.Auto = false;
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
        chart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(216, 43);
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
        series1.Name = "Series1";
        series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
        series2.Name = "Series2";

        chart.Series.Add(series1);
        chart.Series.Add(series2);

        chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 34);
        chart.TabStop = false;

        //Here is the tricky part.  See explanation after code.
        chart.Click += new System.EventHandler(charts_Click);
        myChart.Add(chart);
    }

    return myChart;
}
```

Use it in your main statement like:

```
var MyListofCharts = MakeCharts(myArrayofNames);
```

You can cycle through each chart with a foreach or reference a specific by its control name using linq.  Don't have anything to play with on the control but should look like this for the linq one.

```
var mySelectChart = [Chart]MyListofCharts.First(c => c.Name == "Chart Name");
```

I cast it back out as a type Chart because I believe this might return it as a IEnumerable or something weird like that.

Last is your event.  I do not know the Chart control but your event is going to have to be dynamic since you cannot programmically write a new event handler into your code for each Chart.  The sender object in the click event should contain the control it came from.  If you add a break inside the event that click is in and check the sender object, you should be able to find a property that references the control it came from.  Once you know its type you can cast it out as that type and manipulate the control right from the object and can have 1 event handler for all your chart click events.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I already tried the solution proposed a bit earlier, but I'm also going to try the one of yours for educational purposes because I'm really bad at using methods. Thanks.